# Does the name of episode 12 in season 2 of the Daria series, "Pierce Me", have a sexual meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-play

The name of episode 12 in season 2 of the [Daria series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daria) is "Pierce Me". The episode is about [body piercing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_piercing), however, in the Russian language (my native one) the literal translation of this episode's name (*"проткни меня"*) would imply very strong sexual connotation, something like "*penetrate me*".

Since such jokes are kind of popular in the series, but English is not my native language, I wonder: is something like what I see actually present in the title? Is some other joke implied?

Comment: Whether some dual meaning was implied is not a language question, as any determination solely relies on the context or the intent of the writers. I think this would be better to ask on [*Movies & TV*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) SE. Also questions solely relying on translations are off-topic.

Comment: Barring asking the writers, any answer given here would be entirely subjective.

Comment: I think a dictionary reference that suggests that pierce can have a sexual meaning would help. I'm not aware of any particular sexual meaning of "pierce"

Comment: No, but it's sort of  S&M. Some people might consider that "sexual". At the very least, it can be said to be "kinky", which is why they used it for a title. "piercing" is often associated with pain in English: a piercing pain.

Comment: @JamesK That's basically my question. Can it?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy  I'm saying that *you* should look up the word in a dictionary first. If there is no sexual meaning mentioned in the dictionaries then you may assume that there is no sexual meaning.

Comment: @JamesK The dictionaries that I personally use (particularly multitran.ru, http://context.reverso.net) didn't yield me any such definition, but I bet there are some way better dictionaries for the causes like the one mentioned in this question.

Comment: While this is subjective, I don't think this should be closed as primarily opinion based. The question as I read it is "Does this title have a double meaning in English?" I think we can explain whether or not it's likely that a native speaker would consider "pierce" to have a sexual connotation in this context. There are plenty of sexual double entendre that aren't hinted at in any dictionary but are obvious to many native speakers in context.

Answer (score 2):

Translations of movie titles is an inexact science.

Consider the translations into Russian

> *Silver Linings Playbook* => *My Boyfriend is a Psycho*
>   *No Strings Attached* => *More than Just Sex*
>   *He's Not That Into You* => *A Promise Does Not a Marriage Make*

Other examples are [here](https://www.buzzfeed.com/dianabruk/hilarious-russian-translations-of-hollywood-movie-titles?utm_term=.exeQAd2Kb#.fiW2X1Yod).

My guess is the translation used in your example was meant to have a *double meaning* to attract more attention, as it has piqued your attention.

Comment: I want to note that "Pierce me" is the original title. It was not translated literally in the official translation (if I translated the official one back into English, it would simply say "Piercing").

Comment: So obviously it is a marketing move to use "***Pierce Me***". There are probably other translations in the subtitles of the movie that are not exact.

Comment: "No Strings Attached => More than Just Sex"   That is almost the exact opposite of the original meaning!